# design advice - dynamic table structure

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm in a position where I can design both the database structure and the software for an application which the user imports his own data into the system, and I need yo use that data.

Since the data is variable (mostly indicators) and I don't know in advance what (or how much)    information the user will import into the system, but since the operations to perform are few (sum, average, or filter if the data is a date), I'd been thinking on doing something flexible, instead of a table with "field1, field2, field3,..., fieldN" structure.

I've been studying the EAV model but it's seems to complex for something like this, and I'd like something that could handle a few hundred thousands records efficiently.

Any advice on how do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? In Postgres you could use the key/value store `hstore` or a JSON column.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! I'm using mssql server. I'm not familiar with hstore. Regards!